# C++ Ternary operator when returning a reference

Tags: c++, reference, conditional-operator

I understand that the following function doesn't work because x and y are not on the stack after the return statement.

```
int& max(int x, int y) {
    if (x < y) {
        return x;
    } else {
        return y;
    }
}
```

But why does it work when using the ternary operator like this?

```
int& max(int x, int y) { return (x > y ? x : y); }
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `()`?

Comment: [It doesn't.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rY9Y8675M)

Comment: Still undefined behaviour, the joy of undefined behaviour being that your program can appear to work correctly

Comment: I think "work" ought to be in scare quotes, since I'm getting `warning: reference to stack memory associated with parameter 'x' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]`.

Comment: I know that you should not code like this. The version with the ternary operator is from a question in an assignment. And I'm a bit surprised that it "works".

Comment: As i know local variables should never return a local variable as a reference. It may work by some smart compilers (maybe they convert it somehow), but i think in general it is not a good practice.
More details:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/return-by-reference-in-c-with-examples/

Comment: Appearing to work is not the same as working https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4j755sWbh

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, just your compiler fails to complain.  Sometimes C++ will catch you doing something wrong.  Other times you trick it and your code is bad.

Undefined behaviour, like following a dangling reference, can "appear to work".